# Complex Numbers Real and Imaginary parts

Tags: complex-numbers

Ιf I have a $Z_n= (n^2+in)/(n^2 +1)$  am I right to assume that the real part is $n^2/(n^2 +1)$ and the imaginary part is $in/(n^2+1)$  it seems to simple to be that

Comment: to ass${{{{}}}}$?

Comment: assume @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Sorry I meant assume

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are real, then $b$ is the imaginary part of $a+ib$.

Comment: Imaginary part is $n/(n^2+1)$

Comment: Only, if $n$ is real. If $n$ is complex, you have more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
$$Z_n = \frac{n^2 +in}{n^2+1}= \frac{n^2}{n^2 +1} + \frac{n}{n^2 +1} i $$
So the real part is $\frac{n^2}{n^2 +1}$ and the imaginary is $\frac{n}{n^2 +1}$ (without the $i$).